# What types of diets exist where people avoid meat (e.g. vegetarian, vegan, pescatarian, kosher, jain, raw, etc)?

Tags: diet

Can someone please list out and define all the different types of meatless diets (including diets where only *some* animals are excluded from their diet)?

I'm trying to learn about avoiding/reducing animals from my diet, but my head is spinning trying to keep track of all these names. There's so many!

Is there an authoritative list that actually defines all of these diets that abstain from meat in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any *single* authoritative list, but there are a few that may be helpful

### Airlines

Airlines are special in that they can't just go to the kitchen to make you something special. They've developed a list of "meal codes" for various diets, many of which abstain from meats. Here's the relevant ones:

- KSML - Kosher
- MOML - Muslim
- NLML - Non-lactose
- VGML - Vegan
- RVML - Raw Vegetarian
- VJML - Vegetarian Jain
- VLML - Vegetarian Lacto Ovo
- AVML - Asian Vegetarian
- VOML - Vegetarian Oriental
- FPML - Fruit platter

Comment: See also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/2589/4031